facing problem while installing causalnex
I tried to install causalnex as  !pip install causalnex in jupyter and i got following error .
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.10.0 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.9; 0.11.0 Requires-Python
=3.6, <3.9; 0.11.1 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.11; 0.11.2 Requires-Python >=3.8, <3.11; 0.12.0 Requires-Python >=3.8, <3.11;
0.12.1 Requires-Python >=3.8, <3.11; 0.4.0 Requires-Python >=3.5, <3.8; 0.4.1 Requires-Python >=3.5, <3.8; 0.4.2 Requires-Python >=3.5, <3.8; 0.4.3 Requires-Python >=3.5, <3.8; 0.5.0 Requires-Python >=3.5, <3.8; 0.6.0 Requires-Python >=3.5, <3.8; 0.7.0 Requires-Python >=3.5, <3.8; 0.8.0 Requires-Python >=3.5, <3.8; 0.8.1 Requires-Python >=3.5, <3.8; 0.9.0 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.9; 0.9.1 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.9; 0.9.2 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.9 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement causalnex (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for causalnex


Which Python version are you using?

@Sören 3.11.5 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc.

causalnex-0.12.1 (which is the latest version at the time of writing) only supports Python 3.8/3.9/3.10. Either install one of these, or wait for a new version of causalnex to be released. (Pypi)
